# Why isn't my discord.js bot registering my custom status?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I searched this website from nook and cranny and every solution that I tried hasn't worked. I'm trying to create a custom status for my discord.js bot and using this format isn't working for me. What should I change?

```js
module.exports = {
    name:'ready',
    once: true,
    async execute(client) {
        console.log(`Hello World!! ${client.user.tag} is logged in and online.`);

        client.user.setPresence({ 
            status: "dnd",
            activity: {
                name: "to Spotify",
                type: "LISTENING",
            },
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PresenceData#activity` was replaced with `PresenceData#activities`, which now requires an `Array<ActivitiesOptions>`.

https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#clientuser

```
- client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: 'with discord.js' } });
+ client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: 'with discord.js' }] });
```

Comment: Thanks a million! It worked. But, I can't change the status to do not disturb or idle anymore?

Comment: @snek weird, you can try client.user.setStatus('idle');. If my initial answer helped you, marking it as the solution helps me out alot

Comment: I marked it as the solution. But client.user.setStatus('idle'); doesn't change the status. I looked at the document that you linked and I don't think its an option anymore :(

Comment: @snek according to https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/PresenceData in the official docs it is still an option. It only takes 4 strings https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/PresenceStatusData not sure why its not working for you

Comment: I don't know either. But I'll keep probing at it and see if it works. Thanks, mate :)